# Horizontal button group inside anchor layout

Tags: layout, extjs, anchor

There is a panel with anchor layout used for vertical sizing.
Inside the panel there is a horizontal buttongroup.
Is there a way to set fixed width or better make the width depend on buttons?

In my case it is always stretched to the size of the window.
There is the same problem with the grid inside the panel.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you post the panel/buttongroup code?

Answer (score 0):

Making the width dependent on the buttons is handled by the layout itself. If you have an `hbox` layout, each of the items inside the container (say, buttons) will automatically occupy the width.